# JMeter - Save complete JSON response of all the request to CSV file for test data preparation

Tags: json, csv, testing, jmeter

I need to create test data preparation script and capture JSON response data to CSV file.

In the actual test, I need to read parameters from CSV file.

Is there any possibilities of saving entire JSON data as filed in CSV file (or) need to extract each filed and save it to CSV file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue JSON have comma, You can overcome it by saving JSON to file and use different delimiter instead of comma separated, for example `@`

Then read file using [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) using `@` Delimiter

> Delimiter to be used to split the records in the file. If there are fewer values on the line than there are variables the remaining variables are not updated - so they will retain their previous value (if any).

Also you can save JSON in every row and then get data using different delimiter as `@`

Comment: I have extracted complete JSON to a variable and adding it to a CSV file, Which step i need to change the delimiter. how can i replace delimiter dynamically after extracting JSON response

Comment: @Amit you may save JSON per row without delimiter, but if you need, just concatenate delimiter value after variable

Answer (score 1):

1. You can save entire JSON response into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) by adding a Regular Expression Extractor as a child of the HTTP Request sampler which returns JSON and configuring it like:

   - Name of created variables: anything meaningful, i.e. `response`
   - Regular Expression: `(?s)(^.*)`
   - Template: `$1$`
2. Then you need to declare this `response` as a [Sample Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) by adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   sample_variables=response
   ```
3. And finally you can use [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin/) plugin to store the `response` variable into a file, if you don't have any other Sample Variables you should use `variable#0`

Comment: I need to save response from multiple requests to a file and read them as request in another test